Minisforum NAB6 lite mini pc - SSD is not detected in bios & can't make it boot from SSD (sata / m2). Why is that?
I bought a Mini PC - NAB6 lite by Minisforum (i5-12600H)
Installed ram (DDR4 3200) + SSD (Samsung Evo 860) via sata cable. The ram is detected - i can see it in Bios, but the SSD is NOT detected.
I think, i should see the SSD in first page in bios & in Boot > Boot priorities -  for item "HDD" it should also mention name (brand + model) - as i does, for "USB" when a i have a bootable USB plugged.
I tried installing Ubuntu from bootable USB - this part worked. In the Ubuntu install UI - it DOES see the SSD. I managed to partition it + install ubuntu. After the install, a restart is made - after this it always enter Bios, i never see the SSD as recognised & never managed to make it boot from SSD.
Tested with an m2 drive too, same thing.
Bios version - in home page it says "1.0p" 02/07/24, but in footer bar it "version 2.22"?
Need advice/ help /instructions
Has anyone had encountered this? Found a lot of posts with ~SSD not recognised on various machines, but so far nothing that actually worked..

Any system from 2012 or newer DOESN'T "boot from a drive". It boots from entries saved in the ESP (EFI System Partition). You don't need to "see" the SSD in UEFI (the firmware is called UEFI, not BIOS, again, since ~2012) but surely it's seen, you haven't found it yet. All you need to check and adjust, assuming the OS was correctly installed, and worst case scenario, is the Boot menu where in "OS selection" (or equivalent setting) it should be "Ubuntu", NOT any drive.

What's the question here? Doesn't it boot to Ubuntu? If so have you by any chance created partitions yourself prior to installing? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Now re-reading your question it does indeed suggest you created the partitions manually - managed to partition it + install ubuntu - in which case you should know what you're doing, otherwise let the installer do it automatically. So, the question is: Did you create the ESP? A small FAT32 partition preferably at the beginning of the drive... If you didn't that's why it can't boot now. I suggest you install it again but let the installer do its job automatically.
